# How to compare string, object with string?

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I have a few (string, object) that I need to compare to a string.

string, object looks like: `[password, helloworld]`  and my string looks like `'helloworld'`

When I try to do if(A == B) I get the following error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(string, object)' and 'string'
```

[password, helloworld] is a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Comment: please create and show a [mre]

Comment: Can you post what your object looks like? What are you trying to compare? If it's a `tuple`, then you can compare the second value (which is the string) to the `helloworld` string using the `.Second` property.

Comment: @gUnleash Or is it `.Item2`?

Comment: What do you hope to do with this comparison?

Comment: That's a tuple. Just use .Item 1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Answer (score 2):

Just going off of the error you're getting it looks like you are using a [C# Tuple type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples). Like the comments on your post are saying, you need to reference the item inside of the tuple, rather than compare the tuple itself.

```
public static bool TestDefaultName()
{
    (string, object) tuple = ("password", "helloworld");
    return tuple.Item2.ToString() == "helloworld";
}
```

You can also name the items inside the tuple:

```
public static bool TestCustomName()
{
    (string myString, object myObject) tuple = ("password", "helloworld");
    return tuple.myObject.ToString() == "helloworld";
}
```